# piping the output of gunzip ( of two files ) separately

Tags: shell, unix, pipe, gunzip

I have two compressed files. ( file1.gz and file2.gz ). I would like to unzip them and send the output to another command as separate inputs. something like:

```
gunzip -c file1.gz file2.gz | command -1 file1 -2 file2
```

How could I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can say:

```
command -1 <(gzip -dc file1.gz) -2 <(gzip -dc file2.gz)
```

You can read more about Process Substitution [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Process-Substitution).

Answer (score 0):

Kindly check with below command, it will give you output for list of files exacted.

```
 # ls
 checknum.txt  numbers.txt

 # gzip  checknum.txt numbers.txt

 # ls
 checknum.txt.gz  numbers.txt.gz

 # gunzip -vd *.gz 1>& check ; cat check | awk '{print $6}'
 checknum.txt
 numbers.txt
```

Thanks.